# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection in react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, native

When i run the app, server is not working and nodejs is giving an error.
what does it cause this error ? i didn't found that problem.
How can i fix this problem. i am new in react native world please help me.
Thanks in advance.

**Error Screenshots:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rl6b.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mNob.jpg

Comment: You're probably doing something like this: `fetch('/').then(r=>r.json())` when you should be doing something like this; `fetch('/').then(r=>r.json()).catch(e=>console.log('error:',e))`

Comment: i added every fetch request the catch function.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rl6b.jpg : this warning fixed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mNob.jpg : but still have this error

Answer (score 0):

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/9mNob.jpg]

This error is most like because you're using `JSON.parse(response)` or `response.json()` wrong. You may be parsing the response but the response is not a JSON. Use `console.log` and check the responses

Comment: what should i use instead of "response.json()" or how to edit this code.
Instance of my code: https://ibb.co/88mFrMJ

Comment: I don't know how the response is coming, try `.then(response => console.log(response))` to check what you're receiving from the api